# Kentico 9: How to allow an editor to pick a single custom page type for display

Tags: kentico

I've created a custom page type, and have three 'pages' in a folder. My home page, has a repeater that will select the top 3 pages.

On another page, i need way, from the Page tab, that an editor can select a single node from this folder. I can't see a webpart that will allow this functionality. I had thought of a repeat that only selects based off a node ID, but there will be an editor role that will not have access the design or general tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a widget from the Repeater webpart and expose the path in which they can say they want those items to be displayed from.  All the rest of your properties (transformation, page type, etc.) you will already have defined as default values in the widget.

Then make the area you want to have the editor add those items to is flagged as an Editor zone.  You can do this in the zone properties at the very top.

Comment: When setting up the Widget based on a repeater, ClassName is my custom page name, correct?

Comment: Correct, your name like so: `custom.PageTypeName`.  It's whats in the namespace on the General tab of the page type.

Comment: Thanks. I'll dig more into the documentation now that you've put me on the right path. Cheers.

Comment: I'm struggling just getting a specific item to display. I've exposed the page type and transformation selector, just to ensure they are getting set correctly. I have the path set to Page Selector as well. Is there an example like this in the corporate site?

Comment: When setting the Path property that is a string value so you need to use the URL Selector vs. the Page Selector.

Comment: Thanks. I had just created a new widget using the Universal Page Viewer, just to see if there was another way. Glad it was a simple thing. Cheers!

Comment: Would there be a security setting that would hinder the display when using the URL Selector? When the Path form control is default, i have all my nodes rendering, when i switch to URL selector, and chose a single node, nothing. I thought i had this, but it was a cached.

Comment: I believe the URL Selector would return an Application Relative URL e.g.: ~/langprefixifused/somepath/somepage/ whereas Page Selector would return a NodeAliasPath /somepath/somepage

Comment: Nothing i'm trying is working. I created a new widget, based on the universal page viewer. I placed the same webpart on the page. Using the webpart is fine, but not when i use the widget version. Not sure what i'm missing here.

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a restriction on Widgets with the free license? I've had to back burner this as it wasn't working, but now it's back.